# Prevent spark executors from accessing Mesos or ZooKeeper apis

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zookeeper, mesos

Currently Spark on Mesos is run in [cluster mode](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/running-on-mesos.html#cluster-mode), Mesos/ZooKeeper doesn't have any access control, and executors are started on host network.

What would be the best practice for preventing spark executors from accessing mesos or zookeeper apis when running arbitary code?

- Run executors on overlay network and implement network policies?
- ACL for mesos/zookeeper?
- Something else?

Comment: Storing some Spark state in Zookeeper is useful occasionally (e.g. Kafka offsets for Spark Streaming)

Answer (score 0):

You should enable encryption and authentication in Mesos and Zookeeper. Then you configure ZK [like this](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.6/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_authOptions) and in Mesos `--zk=zk://username:password@host1:port1,host2:port2,.../path`.

To enable authentication in Moses following [theses instructions](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/authentication/)